# how to use the backgroundTask computation expression in F#

Tags: f#

I have tried the following:

```
let o = Object()
let print message =
    // lock to make the console output cleaner
    lock o (fun _ -> printfn $"{message}")
    
let doAndWait name =
    print $"start {name}"
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    print $"end {name}"
    1

let a = backgroundTask { return doAndWait "A" }
let b = backgroundTask { return doAndWait "B" }

print "waiting for nothing"
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
print $"finished: {r.Result}"
let c = a.Result + b.Result
printfn $"finished: {c}"
```

My, obviously wrong, expectation was that the background tasks would start on the thread pool and I could collect the results later.

In practice, 'a' is executed, then 'b' is executed then the 'wait for nothing' code is executed. So the execution is purely sequential.

I was expecting a behavior like this:

```
let x = async { return doAndWait "X" }
let y = async { return doAndWait "Y" }

let r =
    async {
        let! x' = x
        let! y' = y
        return x' + y'
    }
    |> Async.StartAsTask

print "waiting for nothing"
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
print $"finished: {r.Result}"
```

So, I am failing to understand what the 'backgroundTask' CE is. A google search is futile considering the amount of "backgroundTask" strings indexed :D

Comment: What kind of program is this?

Comment: @JimFoye, what do you mean? it's just a test to understand the backgroundTask CE

Comment: Console or GUI?

Comment: it's a simple console test, you can copy/paste it as is and it'll run (probably need to add the open statements to it)

Comment: `backgroundTask` is completed synchronously when started on threadpool thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm looking at the docs here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/task-expressions#background-tasks

It says

> A background task ignores any SynchronizationContext.Current in the
> following sense: if started on a thread with non-null
> SynchronizationContext.Current, it switches to a background thread in
> the thread pool using Task.Run. If started on a thread with null
> SynchronizationContext.Current, it executes on that same thread.

In a GUI application, SynchronizationContext.Current will be non-null, so in that case a backgroundTask would switch to the thread pool. Since you're in a console application, SynchronizationContext.Current will be null, so backgroundTask executes on the same thread.

I haven't actually tried it, but I think that's what is going on.

Comment: I think you may be right. Is there a way to change the synchronization context for the main thread? I'm looking at starting background tasks on another thread and collect the results later

Comment: Yes, but in your case you can just use task instead of background task and then collect the results with Task.WaitAll(). You don't really need to worry about a synchronization context.